# Png won't appear on github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I have my JPG image on the same repo as the index.html. Inside the html I have the exact link for the JPG (which I just went to the image on the repo and got the link),and you can open the image in a new page. But for some reason when i load the page it won't appear.

1)I have checked and its not a case sensitivity problem since I can open the image from the code

This is the link I included in my html (i changed it a bit so it won't go directly to the image in the repo for this post)

```
src="https://github.com/george/Link-tree/blob/master/personal_photo.jpg"
```

So I went to the image in Git hub and copy pasted the link.

Does the JPG need to be moved to another folder?

Comment: Can you show your code? (It's unnecessarily hard to debug what we can't see... )

Comment: because it was just a copy paste of the png link on the repo i didn't, let me know if you need something else.

Comment: The repo seems to be private, so only logged-in users can see it anyways. But I think that the link to the blob doesn't reference an image resource. You could try https://raw.githubusercontent.com/george/Link-tree/master/personal_photo.jpg instead.

Comment: That seems to be fixing the problem! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `blob` link doesn't reference an image resource.
Try `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/george/Link-tree/master/personal_photo.jpg` instead.